# wordpress permalinks with prefix for wildcard

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wildcard, permalinks

I'm having trouble trying to program into Wordpress a wildcard for the permalink structure. So for example, I'm trying to setup a permalink where the link is like this: foo.example.com/company. At the moment, the wildcard is in place for the URL (foo.example.com), but the permalinks are still under the root (example.com/company). Is there a way to program it so that the permalink will be matched exactly to the URL that is written. So if I entered in dsdd.example.com, the permalinks will display dsdd.example.com/company, etcc...

This kind of thing is way over my head, so if someone could provide some code examples of how to accomplish this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're gonna have to dig into the wordpress help sites and files. Google the problem, there are resources ... permalinks are very annoying at times.

Comment: Heheh, yeah I know @HowardPautz, they are very annoying. I've spent the last 4 hours Googling this, and am going around in circles. I'll keep digging though. Hopefully someone who has experience with this kind of thing can provide some assistance as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your current setup is, but I can offer advice based on my prior experience with web hosts and WordPress.

If you want to have something where the subdomain (something.example.com) is a wildcard (thiscouldbeanything.example.com) and still point to your WordPress installation, you're going to have to get your host to set up something called a [Wildcard DNS Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record)

From your description, you might have this set up already. If so, cool.

Using the wildcard is another story. Personally, I would go with a .htaccess file, and use mod_rewrite in order to have it use the wildcard subdomain to be used in the URL.

WordPress MU (Multi User) uses something along these lines to help you set up a subdomain network, and you can probably use their [.htaccess file demonstrated here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite)

Without REALLY specific information about your setup and goals, I couldn't be as much help as I wanted to be, but good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Tim. Yes, we have setup a wildcard DNS Record, both on DNS and on the web host. I imagine we would either have to do something with the .htaccess or wp-config file. We originally had Wordpress multisite set up, but the wildcard wasn't working. It seemed to only work with a single site. But our setup at the moment is a single installation of wordpress, with a wildcard * set for our domain name (example.com). The goal is to have each wildcard entry show the same content as described above. The permalinks would include wildcard entry in it. Code snippet examples are useful